# Undefined reference in extern arrays that are initialized in another file

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm finding trouble understanding how to declare variables that exist in the scope of the whole application.

So, I declare an `extern` array and then delegate its initialization to the appropriate `cpp` file (`trigonometry.cpp`). Following the logic that once I call this initialization function, these extern arrays should exist everywhere and have values. But obviously that's not what's happening.

Below is the pertinent code.

---

Error output:

```sh
player.o: In function `Player::yDirection() const':
player.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `Trigonometry::fSinTable'
```

Header file where I declare the extern variable.

```cpp
// trigonometry.hpp

namespace Trigonometry
{

extern double fSinTable[Config::ANGLE360 + 1];

bool load();
}; // namespace Trigonometry
```

The function where I *init* the values of `fSinTable`

```cpp
// trigonometry.cpp

bool Trigonometry::load()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != (Config::ANGLE360 + 1); ++i)
    {
        double radian = arcToRad(i) + (0.0001); // Add 0.0001 to avoid division by zero
        double fSinTable[i] = {std::sin(radian)};
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The class where I'm trying to access the array

```cpp
// player.cpp

#include "trigonometry.hpp"
#include "player.hpp"

const double &Player::yDirection() const
{
    return Trigonometry::fSinTable[_rotation];
}
```

And my main class where I try to call the initialization function before everything else.

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include "config.hpp"
#include "trigonometry.hpp"
#include "player.hpp"

// ...

// This executes before &Player::yDirection(), so I would expect Trigonometry::fSinTable to be initialized
bool loaded = Trigonometry::load();

Player *player;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   player = new Player();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

This is how I build the application:

```
g++    -c -o trigonometry.o trigonometry.cpp
g++    -c -o player.o player.cpp
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -o App trigonometry.o player.o main.o
```

Comment: How do you build your application?

Comment: @StoryTeller Updated the description with my building command. Thanks

Comment: "extern" in this context means "I have defined the array somewhere else, here is what it looks like".  It is now the job of the linker to find it back.  It could not, agrees with the snippets since they don't define it anywhere either.  Put it in, say, trigonometry.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I see that my error was not defining `fSinTable` anywhere.

I was wrongly defining each child of the array instead of the whole array.

So, from this:

```cpp
// trigonometry.cpp

#include "trigonometry.hpp"

bool Trigonometry::load()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != (Config::ANGLE360 + 1); ++i)
    {
        double radian = arcToRad(i) + (0.0001); // Add 0.0001 to avoid division by zero
        double fSinTable[i] = {std::sin(radian)};
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To this:

```cpp
// trigonometry.cpp

#include "trigonometry.hpp"

double Trigonometry::fSinTable[Config::ANGLE360 + 1];

bool Trigonometry::load()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != (Config::ANGLE360 + 1); ++i)
    {
        double radian = arcToRad(i) + (0.0001); // Add 0.0001 to avoid division by zero
        fSinTable[i] = std::sin(radian);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hans-pasant for your reply!